# Asynchronous rest call blocking

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I can't fathom why this isn't working. Inside a Jersey resource method I make an asynchronous call, but the code blocks and never returns. Testing with curl, my terminal just hangs. From application logs, I can tell the request got intercepted and the code was executed.

Using Jersey 2.8 with maven tomcat7 plugin.

I also tried using an Executor Service instead of creating the thread directly, this is how I'd prefer to do it. Changed to creating a thread directly to be close to the documentation.

**Jersey code:**

```
@Path("/trade")
public class TradeEndpoint {
    // TODO: make this configurable!!
    private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);


    private static MyService myService;

    static {
        //issues getting Spring working, so get it like this
        orderFillService = Bootstrapper.getOrderFillService();
    }

    @GET
    public String getFoo() {
        return "Foo";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("limit")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public void limitOrder(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response, Model model) {
        System.out.println(model);

        new Thread( new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                myService.doStuff(model);

            }

        }).start();

        System.out.println("SUBMITTED");
    }
```

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.foo.conf.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Funny how logic hits you after you post your question. I guess I don't need to suspend, because I'm not sending anything back to the client, BUT I'm still curious why this doesn't work. When I remove @Suspend, it kicks off the thread and does its business.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `web-app version="3.0"`